# Числительное 71 с прилагательным

Tags: склонение, числительные, прилагательные

Как правильно написать: ***"выявлено 71 административное правонарушение"*** или ***"выявлено 71 административных правонарушений"***?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *административное правонарушение.* Потому что *семьдесят одно*.

Comment: Лучше не отвечать, чем отвечать не аргументируя.

Comment: Я аргументировал: "Потому что семьдесят одно".

Comment: Это логика, а не аргумент. Как же *одно*, если нарушений много, т. е. не одно?

Comment: Потому что числительные так согласуются в русском языке.

Comment: В ответе нет цитаты, ссылки на источник этого знания, нет примеров употребления, нет самого слова *согласование*. Следует верить на слово?

Comment: Попробуйте склонить "семьдесят одно" так, чтобы оно согласовалось с "административных нарушений". Мой вариант - вообще единственный, который можно произнести. Вот и источник знания. В таких случаях ссылаться на учебники/справочники - это, я считаю, лютый формализм. Всё равно что с помощью учебников физики доказывать человеку, что он не сумеет, взмахивая руками, взлететь.